# Cannot change default path to php on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: php, path, osx-snow-leopard, mamp

I have installed MAMP on OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.8) and I want to change the default path for PHP.

I tried both of the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path), and on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857068/change-the-php-path-to-mamps-php), and in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2607040?start=0&tstart=0) but when I'm trying `which php` in Terminal I still get `/usr/bin/php`.

I'm starting to get the impression that I'm doing something profoundly wrong, so any idea about what that might be, will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because `/usr/bin` has a higher precedence in `$PATH` than your new location. Either remove the `/usr/bin/php` file from your computer or alter your `$PATH` variable so the new location appears before `/usr/bin`

Comment: @DaveRandom It's **terrible** advice to remove `/usr/bin/php` just to fix path problems.

Comment: @DaveRandom the result of `echo $PATH` is this:


`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was an issue with permissions. 
Everything was fixed by running this command:

`sudo chmod -R 764 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin`

Answer (score 0):

The correct path to PHP in MAMP is this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3/bin
```

NOT

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin
```

First view your actual PHP:

```
which php
```

If you actual path is: **/usr/bin/php** you can change with this commands:

In you personal folder:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Then copy this text:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH
```

Type esc and :wq to save & exit.

Solved!